# from where am I getting the random values in this tensor?

Tags: python, matrix, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I have a very simple code:

```
linear = nn.Linear(3, 4)

# Create ones (batch_size, 3) as input

input = torch.ones(5, 3)

# Use the linear layer to compute the output

output = linear(input)

print(output) # should be (batch_size, 4)
print(input)
print(linear)
```

with this output

```
tensor([[-0.0253,  0.3926, -0.5856,  0.7869],
        [-0.0253,  0.3926, -0.5856,  0.7869],
        [-0.0253,  0.3926, -0.5856,  0.7869],
        [-0.0253,  0.3926, -0.5856,  0.7869],
        [-0.0253,  0.3926, -0.5856,  0.7869]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
Linear(in_features=3, out_features=4, bias=True)
```

**I would like to know from where comes the random (5,4) tensor.
How can I change it to all 0 ?**

**EDIT**

What's wrong with this code?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking why your tensor is 5x4 or how to set the values all to zero?

Comment: @JesseSealand I think that (5,4) somehow comes from (3,4) and (5,3). But I do not know why it is a **random matrix** and where can I set it to be all **0**. It is not that all zeroes would be somehow interesting but I want to know where to change it in this way.

Comment: When you use nn.Linear the values are initialized according to a specific formula. [Ref](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html). Why would you zero it out if you just constructed it to take an input?

Comment: The thing is that I do not know **where** have I constructed it. [Here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) `>>> input = torch.randn(128, 20)` is `randn` which makes it easy to see why the matrix is random. But in my code example there is **no** `randn`.

Comment: It's created when you call nn.Linear. the first line:  linear = nn.Linear(3, 4)

Comment: @JesseSealand Right. How can I change it to my own values ? Just with `linear=tensor([[1,2],[3,4]])` instead of `linear = nn.Linear(3, 4)` ?

Comment: Please do not use "input" as a variable name because it's a reserved word in python. Your tensor "linear" is 1-d it needs to be 2 dimensional. Try wrapping it in another set of [], this should make it a (1×3) rather than just (3). Then the dimension checks should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create Tensor from list**:

If you want to initialize a Pytorch Tensor with your own values this can quickly be done as follows:

```
import torch

my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
my_tensor = torch.tensor(my_list)
```

Comment: I'm getting a weird error, please see my **EDIT**. I wanted to compute `output` from `input` and `linear` via a matrix multiplication. How should the correct formula look like ?

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply matrices (or tensors) in python with *A*B*, it attemps to multiply each *a<sub>ij</sub>* from *A* with *b<sub>ij</sub>* from *B*; thus, in order for this to work, both *A* and *B* must be of the same dimensions *m x n*. To do true matrix multiplication, one can use *@*.

```
import torch

my_list = [[0.9651, 0.6681, 0.4902, -0.4438],
           [0.9651, 0.6681, 0.4902, -0.4438],
           [0.9651, 0.6681, 0.4902, -0.4438]]

linear = torch.tensor(my_list)

input = torch.ones(5,3)

output = input @ linear

print("A")
print(output)
```

Output:

```
A
tensor([[ 2.8953,  2.0043,  1.4706, -1.3314],
        [ 2.8953,  2.0043,  1.4706, -1.3314],
        [ 2.8953,  2.0043,  1.4706, -1.3314],
        [ 2.8953,  2.0043,  1.4706, -1.3314],
        [ 2.8953,  2.0043,  1.4706, -1.3314]])
```

Since the left multiplying matrix is *5 x 3* and the right is *3 x 4*, the output is *5 x 4*. Since one way of looking at matrix multiplication is that the rows of the output are linear combinations of the rows of the right multiplying input matrix, in this case each of the 5 rows of the output are the sum of the 3 rows of `my_list` or `linear`. Finally, since each of the rows of `my_list` and `linear` are identical, each of the 5 rows of the output matrix is `3 * [0.9651, 0.6681, 0.4902, -0.4438]`.

As you noticed, creation of `nn.Linear(3,4)` creates weights from a random distribution as noted in the documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html.